# How can I isolate a single value from a list within an awk field?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, solaris

Lets say i have a file called test and in this file contains some data:

```
jon:TX:34:red,green,yellow,black,orange
```

I'm trying to make it so it will only print the 4th field up until the comma and nothing else. But I need to leave the current FS in place because the fields are separated by the ":". Hope this makes sense.

I have been running this command:

```
awk '{ FS=":"; print $4 }' /test
```

I want my output to look like this.

```
jon:TX:34:red
```

or if you could even just figure out how i could just print the 4th field would be a good help too

```
red
```

Comment: What's the expected output? "red"? sounds like a job for `cut`

Comment: please edit your question (Q) to show your required output AND your current output. Good luck.

Comment: @knittl updated it. I dont want to cut it though i just want to print it hmm

Comment: Just printing an extracted field is what `cut` _does_ (though `awk` is perfectly capable of doing that too)

Comment: @Namaste not sure I understand. `cut` outputs whatever field you specify. From your description it sounds like you want to cut the first field of the fourth field (or just the first field, depending on your delimiter; you have provided _two_ expected outputs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have

```
jon:TX:34:red,green,yellow,black,orange
```

and desired output is

```
jon:TX:34:red
```

then just treat input as comma-separated and get 1st field, which might be expressed in GNU `AWK` as

```
echo "jon:TX:34:red,green,yellow,black,orange" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{print $1}'
```

gives output

```
jon:TX:34:red
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that `,` character is field separator (`FS`), for each line I `print` 1st column (`$1`)

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: Unless awk is a requirement or cut is not available, I'd still suggest using cut: `cut -d, -f1` is a lot less typing (and IMHO a simpler command) than `awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{print $1}'` (could be shortened to `awk -F, '{print $1}'`, but that's still more characters to type)

Answer (score 2):

It's overkill for your needs but in general to print the `y`th `,`-separated subfield of the `x`th `:`-separated field of any input would be:

```
$ awk -F':' -v s=',' -v x=4 -v y=1 '{split($x,a,s); print a[y]}' file
red
```

Answer (score 2):

Or

```
awk -F '[:,]' '{print $4}' test
```

output

```
red
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to extract the first field of the fourth field. Top level fields are delimited by ":" and the nested field is delimited by ",".

Combining two [`cut`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) processes achieves this easily:

```
<input.txt cut -d: -f4 | cut -d, -f1
```

If you want all fields until the first comma, extract the first comma-delimited field without first cutting on colon:

```
cut -d, -f1 input.txt
```

Comment: so what does the -d do?

Comment: @Namaste it sets the field delimiter

Comment: `man cut` can probably answer your question. Get used to using `man <prog>` to cut down your development time (-;! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

if you want a purely `regex` approach :

```
 echo 'jon:TX:34:red,green,yellow,black,orange' |
```

> ```
> mawk NF=NF FS='.+:|,.+' OFS=
> ```

```
red
```

if you only want `"red"` without the trailing newline (`"\n"`), use `RS/ORS` instead of `FS/OFS` — (the `%` is the command prompt, i.e. no trailing `\n`):

> ```
> mawk2 8 RS='.+:|,.+' ORS=
> ```

```
red%
```

if u wanna hard-code in the `$4` :

> ```
> gawk '$_= $4' FS=,\|:         # gawk or nawk
> mawk '$!NF=$4' FS=,\|:        # any mawk
> ```

```
red
```

and if you only want the non-numeric text :

> ```
> nawk NF=NF  FS='[!-<]+' OFS='\f\b'
> ```

```
jon
  TX
   red
     green
         yellow
              black
                  orange
```